# Text manipulation: Extract everything inside brackets

Tags: text-processing, sed, perl

I have a text file where every line is in a similar format to this:

```
%#&#%#    [Dinero]    / Money / 
!#@%$@    [Dia]     / Day /
$%&$^#@ [Perro]   / Dog /
```

I am looking to extract the words inside the brackets, ie. Ola, Dinero, Perro, etc, and save it all to a new text file line by line. Essentially, I am looking to omit/delete/erase *all* words, letters, special characters, and anything else outside the brackets, including the brackets themselves.

Answer (score 5):

with the help of `awk`,

```
$ awk -F'[][]' '{print $2}' < input
Dinero
Dia
Perro
```

Using `grep`,

```
grep -oP '\[\K[^\]]+' input
```

`\K` means that use *look around* regex advanced feature. More precisely, it's a *positive look-behind assertion*

if you lack the `-P` option, you can do this with `perl`:

```
perl -lne '/\[\K[^\]]+/ and print $&' input
```

use `-i` option to edit file in place.

Or simply you can use `cut` as suggested by @juliepelletier,

```
cut -d"[" -f2 < input | cut -d"]" -f1
```

Comment: For the sake of simplicity, I was thinking of answering: `cat input|cut -d\[ -f2|cut -d\] -f1`

Comment: @juliepelletier yes, updated your suggestion in answer. Thanks

Comment: You even golfed it nicely.

Comment: huh, I've not actually used the \K flag. seems useful. Given the requirements, I'd have simply done `grep -o -e '\[.*\]' file.txt | sed -e 's/\[//' -e 's/\]//'` to find and extract all words with the brackets surrounding them and then strip away the brackets. And yes, that's the slightly verbose variant - could also be done more concisely with the same effect. It just better describes the flow I'd have put the data through. I keep meaning to pick up awk but I can never find the time.

Comment: I think you need <input, not > input

Comment: @MatthewFinlay I have not used `> input` anywhere in my post.

Comment: @Rahul $ awk -F'[][]' '{print $2}' > input

Comment: @MatthewFinlay Ah, silly typo. Anyway thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 's/^.*\[//;s/\].*$//' /path/to/input > /path/to/output
```